# Direct3d world to screen

Tags: c++, direct3d

I'm new in direct3d and i got a newbie question.
I got a point in the world and the location of the camera. I would like to know where i will see the point on my screen. I know the width/height of my screen, the field of view of the camera and everything else. I think that there will be function that do that and i don't need to calculate my self.

I searched a lot and couldn't find it, how do i do that?
The only thing i found is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205516%28VS.85%29.aspx but i didn't understand what to give to him (im new in direct3d as i said)
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Direct3D is not a solution to world to screen transformation, it is an API that lets you use the GPU to solve that problem faster on the GPU, but if you don't know, how to do it without Direct3D, then Direct3D will probably of no help. So you have to learn the linear Algebra, and the Rendering Pipeline (which is already documented in a lot of places).